# Add a description to all document library dynamically

Tags: document-library, custom-actions

It's possible to add a description via content editor web part. But have too many document libraries, I just want to add it dynamically

[image]

It would be very great if you could help me with my problem.

Comment: Add you script in master page.

Comment: Thank you,  is it able to add the master page to document library level?

Comment: yes. you just need some configuration. you can find your **Library Name** using `ctx.ListTitle`. Configuration example: `if (ctx.ListTitle == "A"){var des = "Test description"}`

Answer (score 1):

the below endpoint can get you the description

```
http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘Test')
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using managed client object model, you can add web part to the the page. You just need to have Url of the page.

```
using (ClientContext context =new ClientContext(""))
{
   Web web = context.Web;
   File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("Page Url");//Page Url is the page where you want to add webpart.Doc lib view.keep all libraries in collection and traverse and get the view url of it
   context.Load(file);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   LimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
   WebPartDefinition def = wpm.ImportWebPart(WebpartData);
   wpm.AddWebPart(def.WebPart, "Main", 0);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

what is `WebpartData` data?

```
WebPartDefinition def = wpm.ImportWebPart(WebpartData);
```

`WebpartData` is the string variable which contains webpart data in xml.

Initially add your CEWP on one page and export this webpart and assign the content of .dwp file to `WebpartData` before above code.

for example.

```
   public static string WebpartContent = @"<WebPart                xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2"">
  <Title>Content Editor</Title>
  <FrameType>Default</FrameType>
  <Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>Main</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>0</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version= 16.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
  <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>
  <ContentLink xmlns =""http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"">/sites/testsite/SiteAssets/Calender_Weekend_Color.txt</ContentLink>  
 <PartStorage xmlns = ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"" />
 </WebPart>";
```